# Access SQL computed columns through ActiveRecord

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, calculated-columns

I have a `Person` model, which includes a property representing the data of birth (`birth_date`).

I also have a method called `age()`, which works out the current age of the person.

I now have need to run queries based on the person's age, so I have replicated the logic of `age()` as a computed column in MySQL.

I cannot workout how I would make this additional column part of the default select statement of the model.

I would like to be able to access the age as if it were a native property of the Person model, to perform queries against it and access the value in my views.

Is this possible, or am barking up the wrong tree?

I thought I might be able to define additional fields through `default_scope` or `scope`, but these methods seem to only recognise existing fields. I also tried `default_scope` in tandem with `attr_assessor`.

Possible workarounds I've considered but would prefer not to do:

- Create an actual property called `age` and populate through the use of callbacks. The date is always changing, so this obviously would be be reliable.
- Replicate the logic in ActiveRecord as `age()` and in a scope as a where cause. This would achieve what I need, but doesn't feel very DRY.
- I am already caching the results of the `age()` method. it is the ability to use the field in where clauses that I am most interested in.

There must be a way to define dynamic fields through SQL that I can access through the model by default.

Any help would be appreciated.

Rich

**UPDATE**

An example of my failed attempt to utilise scopes:

```
default_scope :select => "*, 2 as age"

attr_accessor :age
```

`age` is blank, I assume because scopes only deal with limiting, not extending.

Comment: Please show some code.  have you set some aliases for additional attributes, like `select('expression AS alias')` ?

Comment: @taro, I've added an example.

Comment: I think, attr_accessor declaration is not needed.

Comment: @taro, no but I don't think it's the problem either.

Comment: have you tried to remove that declaration?

Comment: @taro: Dude, form that as answer, you deserve every bit of that bounty. I cannot believe I didn't try that. Thank you so much.

Comment: Have you considered to use a stored function in MySQL to calculate the age in your query? You then can add a scope like `:select => "age(birth_date) > 18"` or use lamda function enabled scope to have variable ages.

Comment: Thanks @arnep, yes I have. But what do you mean by "lamda function enabled scope to have variable ages", you've peaked my interest.

Comment: Great, but I don't care about the prize :)

Comment: Thanks again @taro. I would like to have the answer clearly defined. I can answer it myself, but I would prefer credit to go where it is due. I will not submit my answer for a couple of days, in case you change your mind.

Comment: @kim3er: you can read about lambda function in named scopes in the [Rails API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NamedScope/ClassMethods.html). For your problem it would be: `scope :age, lambda {|age| :conditions => ["age(birch_date) > ?", age] }`. Or just use one of the [many possibilities](http://www.google.de/#q=mysql+age+from+date+of+birth) to calculate the actual age in this scope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

kim3er your solution to your problem is simple. Follow these steps:

Loose the `attr_accessor :age` from your model. You simply don't need it.

Leave the default scope at the `Person` model: `default_scope :select => "*, 2 as age"`

Lastly open up a console and try

```
p = Person.first
p.age
=> 2
```

When you define a select using as, `Rails` will automagically add those methods on the instances for you! So the answer to your question:

> There must be a way to define dynamic fields through SQL that I can access through the model by default.

is:

> Rails

Comment: Thanks Gerry. @taro had already answered my question in the comments above, but I appreciate the extra context you've provided, so I'll mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert by any stretch, but it seems you want:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base

scope :exact_age, lambda { |a| where('age = ?', a) }
scope :age_gt, lambda { |a| where('age > ?', a) }
```

but that said, I've just started looking at [Arel](http://rdoc.info/github/rails/arel/master/file/README.markdown), seems pretty cool

Comment: +1 Thanks @Michael K Madison, Arel looks pretty slick I'll check it out.

Comment: Thanks.  Also look at [Metawhere](http://metautonomo.us/projects/metawhere/)  seems even easier!