# ActiveRecord deep nested query and computed column

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, subquery

Here are the associations,

`Publication` : has_many `exchange_rates`, `books` and `authors`

`Book` belongs_to `author`, `exchange_rate`

`Author` belongs_to `exchange_rate`

I am trying to write a query to find `books` with one extra `computed_column`.

**This is the query I have tried so far,**

```
publication.books.joins(:exchange_rate, :author).select("books.*, (exchange_rates.exchange_ratio + (SELECT exchange_rates.exchange_ratio FROM exchange_rates WHERE exchange_rate_id = authors.exchange_rate_id)) AS computed_column")
```

My aim is to generate a column which computed from associated tables attributes.

That means,

```
book.exchange_rate.exchange_ratio + book.author.exchange_rate.exchange_ration AS computed_column
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `computed_column` as an `attr_accessor` on `Book`

```ruby
class Book
  attr_accessor :computed_column
end
```

Then each instance of `Book` in your query will have `book.computed_column` available

For reference: [Access SQL computed columns through ActiveRecord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6741156/access-sql-computed-columns-through-activerecord)

Comment: `computed_column` is just a dummy column which contains computed value. No need of `attr_accessor` here.

Comment: The reason for the `attr_accessor` is so that Rails knows what to do with `computed_column` when it retrieves it in the SQL query. If your model doesn't have a column or accessor set up with that name, Rails will discard the column

Comment: We are not fetching a virtual column that contains computed value. It doesn't required `attr_accessor`.

Comment: Unfortunately then, I don't understand the nature of your question. I thought that was what you wanted to do. Would you mind explaining in more detail?

Comment: I want to fetch db columns and 1 extra which having the calculate value. Sort of `sum of two column`.

Comment: Do you need help with your rails code or your mysql query?

Comment: I see. I apologize for misunderstanding. Let me see if I can re-write my answer to get the query working

Comment: What currently happens when you try this?

Comment: When I tried the above command, got error that in  `authors.exchange_rate_id` `authors` is undefined variable.